# Do all my log sources need to use the same field names with the ELK stack?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-4, elastic-stack

If I have a number of different sources for logs all logging to the same Elasticsearch cluster, do all those sources need to use the same field names for the same information if I want to make correlations between different sources?

For example say three different sources used the names "Machine", "MachineName", and "Computer" to identify the computer that sent the log message. Is there anyway to associate these values to one another? I didn't see anything like a "field alias" in the documentation.

Is there anyway around having to keep track of all these property names between sources?

Are there any documented conventions for field names?

Comment: How do you ship your logs? If you use Logstash, I suggest mutating the fields in a filter in order to name them all the same.